# How does AppEngine(or its embedded-server) processes different urls

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty, http-status-code-404

I created a simple appengine project that accesses a restful webservice hosted in http://commerce.qa.mycomp.com (mycomp should be replaced with my actual company name).

I am using the Jersey Client to make the client request. I do a POST request to the above url.
When I run the application locally, it always returns 404 Not Found response. For experimenting, I did a POST request to http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/ and this works fine, and returns 200 as the status.

I just decoupled my app from appengine and ran it in the separately-configured tomcat server, and there it works fine and returns 200 status code. I think appengine uses Jetty as the server. Does Jetty have any bugs processing urls like commerce.qa.mycomp.com. Why I am asking this is urls that start with www.any.com seems to be working fine.

The two code snippets shown below is not working when run within appengine locally(not running even if I host it to appspot).

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource service = client.resource("http://commerce.qa.mycomp.com/rest");
ClientResponse response = service
    .header("Content-Type", "text/xml; Charset=utf-8")
.header("Authorization", "Basic dwt3hkl553lsfsfssf3")
.post(ClientResponse.class, "does not need to be actual xml");

URL url = new URL("http://commerce.qa.mycomp.com/rest");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; Charset=utf-8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dwt3hkl553lsfsfssf3");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write("no need to be actual xml".getBytes());
os.flush();
System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
```

But when run with tomcat, it just works.

My installations are:
Google App Engine Java SDK 1.6.1
Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7
jersey-client-1.12, jersey-core-1.12, jersey-json-1.8

Please share thoughts.

Comment: Does your app have any handler/mapping for target url?

Comment: Nope, I don't have any such mapping for the target url.

Comment: So, why it should respond with 200? 404 is correct answer for non existing url.

Comment: I've disconnected the internet and tried this. client.resource("http://commerce.qa.mycomp.com/rest") returns 404 status and client.resource("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") returns 200. Now it's clear that appengine/jetty caches the request. How can I disable this cache?

Comment: Hm, why it's clear? Can't see any tie here. You don't have any mapping for `/rest`, so you should have 404.

Comment: This seems to be a strange bug. A client request(jersey-client) from a appengine seems to be not working. Is this a bug or something I misundestood. Even if I disconnect the internet and run it locally, for one url it returns 200 status code and for another it returns 404 status.

Comment: What do you get for wget/curl on this urls?

Comment: For the curl, I get the following(connected to internet):                                HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Netscape-Enterprise/4.1
Authorization: dXNyPWdpcmlAZ2J1eWVyLCB0b
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 22 May 2012 09:04:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Ok, seems that you have internet access